# Clear innerHTML of dynamically loaded elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Everything i have read, leads more to event handlers being added using .live(), .on(), .bind(), .delegate(), etc..

I asked a question earlier that may not be coming across correctly, so i voted to delete that one and re-ask a much simpler one, from which i can do the rest i believe.

Is there a way to clear the innerhtml of an HTML element with a predefined class, including those loaded dynamically via AJAX, etc.

So every time an ajax call puts

```
<div class="triggerElement">something here...</div>
```

or similar on the page, i need it to be emptied. I think i have explained that correctly. Just let me know if not.

EDIT

Seems to be a lot of confusion. .empty & others like it will not work. If you call

```
$(".omButton").empty();
```

from the index, then some other module loads something later via AJAX with that same class, it WILL NOT empty that. If i have the element on the page first, then call it, yes it will work....

I need something along the lines of .live or .delegate that will work for any content loaded after the fact, as i have tried .empty and .html and neither work for the content that is loaded with AJAX.

Not sure how else to explain this. Thought it was pretty simple. Sorry!

EDIT 2...

index contains empty function

```
$(function(){
    $('.omButton').empty();
    $ajax... to load "loadedContent"
});

<div class="omButton"></div>
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
```

ajax returns

```
json_encode(array('test' => '<div class="omButton">Button Text</div>'));
```

So now the HTML on the index is

```
<div id="loadedContent"><div class="omButton">Button Text</div></div>
```

However since the inner div was not there when the page loaded, the .empty does not effect it. I need something that i can put on the page load that "monitors" for any occurance (static or dynamic) of it and empties it.

Hopefully that helps?

Comment: Like `$(".triggerElement").html("");`?

Comment: or `$(".triggerElement").empty();` [.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: Very poor research effort... just google "jquery empty element"

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, OP is searching for Mutation Observers.

Comment: Show us your code for adding dynamic content. The empty code needs to be part of it.

Comment: @AustinBest we need this part: *`$ajax... to load "loadedContent"`* that's where your empty code would go.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such. If you have a clarification for an existing answer, please edit said answer. Same with the question.

Comment: @George, who are you talking to? I posted that one of the below answers worked, also upvoted and checked it. What i did with it will do no one any good bcause it is all custom code. Any other purpose for your message? Something on this site that tracks posts for "points" or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [$.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) - as this is triggered after every ajax request completes

```
$('body').ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('.triggerElement').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    complete: function(){
        $(elementSelectorForWhatYouWantEmptied).empty();
    }
})
```

or if the element that is loaded is dynamically placed in the DOM, then you can use `.live()`.

```
$(elementThatIsInDOM).on(event, elementSelectorThatIsDynamicallyAdded, function(){
    $(elementSelectorForWhatYouWantEmptied).empty();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work on dynamically loaded content.

Comment: You're telling me that if you run that statement when there is an element with the `triggerElement` class that it will not clear it? I think that the problem lies with *what* is triggering the `.empty()`.

Comment: My answer from 11 mins ago is not for the edited content of your current reply. I can not put it in the AJAX response because it is from 3rd party programmers. I need it to be done dynamically on the fly without any interaction from programming. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: But what is the event that triggers the `.empty()`?

Comment: $(document).on(event, '.omButton', function(){$('.omButton').empty();}) That is about the best i could figure on your second suggestion, but it also fails to empty the element.

Comment: i added a 2nd edit to the initial post, maybe that will help?

Comment: Nope. I unfortunately do not think that you are explaining your issue properly. As others have commented, a jsFiddle would help greatly here or even more code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading content using ajax, and that content is a full on tag with content

```
<div class="triggerElement">something here...</div>
```

And you want to `empty` that element after it is loaded, you need to do that within the callback which gets executed when the data is loaded.

```
$.ajax(
    ....
    success: function(data){
      $(".omButton").empty();
    });
```

Comment: Ok, so you are on the right track, BUT i dont want to do it in the ajax call. This requires 3rd party programmers to do it. I want to ensure it is done correctly from the "core" of the project. So something like the .live or .delegate needs to set that "triggerElement" innerHTML to something else once it is served via AJAX. Am i making sense at all lol? Sorry!